# ggplot bar chart two dataframes same variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets with identical variables where the only difference is that the variable "count" is more restrictive in dataframe2 than in dataframe1. I want to create a bar chart that shows, for each month, two bars next to each other showing the "count" variable in each dataframe. I tried the code below but it does not work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? And is it possible to manually create a legend in this figure?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=data1, aes(x = as.Date(date), y = count), stat = "identity", fill="red") +
  geom_bar(data=data2, aes(x = as.Date(date), y = count), stat = "identity", fill="blue") +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 3)+
  labs(y= "Counts", 
       x = "Date",
       title = "Results") +
  theme_classic()
```

My dataset "data1" looks like this:

```
structure(list(year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2023), month = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1), 
    count = c(8, 9, 15, 14, 8, 9, 7, 14, 18, 10), date = structure(c(2022.25, 
    2022.33333333333, 2022.41666666667, 2022.5, 2022.58333333333, 
    2022.66666666667, 2022.75, 2022.83333333333, 2022.91666666667, 
    2023), class = "yearmon")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    year = c(2022, 2023), .rows = structure(list(1:9, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

And my dataset "data2" looks like this:

```
structure(list(year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2023), month = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1), 
    count = c(6, 5, 14, 12, 5, 7, 6, 15, 17, 9), date = structure(c(2022.25, 
    2022.33333333333, 2022.41666666667, 2022.5, 2022.58333333333, 
    2022.66666666667, 2022.75, 2022.83333333333, 2022.91666666667, 
    2023), class = "yearmon")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    year = c(2022, 2023), .rows = structure(list(1:9, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the first of two `data2` really `data1`?

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: `My dataset "data2" looks like this:` and then `And my dataset "data2" looks like this:`. Both say `data2`.

Comment: Also, your code fails for me in two other ways: `! do not know how to convert 'date' to class "Date"` due to `yearmon`, not sure which library you've loaded to automate that, plus `geom_text(.)` fails without the required `label=` aesthetic, which you have not defined.

Comment: It works fine for me. Actually I also tried adding labels in the bars but I did not manage. I have the following packages installed: 
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(quantmod)
library(viridis)
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)
library(countrycode)
library(expss)
library(formattable)
library(areaplot)
library(lubridate)
library(runner)
library(readxl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you combine the datasets and use just a single `geom_bar`.

I'll remove the `geom_text` since you don't have a label, and I'll remove `as.Date` since that is erring for me.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(data1=data1, data2=data2, .id = "source") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = date, y = count, fill = source), stat = "identity") +
  # geom_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 3)+
  labs(y= "Counts", x = "Date", title = "Results") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: stacked barplot]

It might be that you want the bars side-by-side, so replace the `geom_bar` above with

```r
# ...
  geom_bar(aes(x = date, y = count, fill = source), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
# ...
```

[image: side-by-side barplot]

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! I will you the second chart you suggest. How can I add the labels? I tried with "  geom_label_repel(label = count, nudge_x = 0.35, size = 3)" but it does not change anything